# image_Tap(int x, int y) - is it possible in Windows Phone application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, methods

I have something about 100 images. Is it possible to use method `image_Tap(int x,int y)` where `x` and `y` are different for each image? I want use `image_Tap(0,0)` for `image1`, `image_Tap(0,1)` for `image2` etc... How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found better way to do this. I called my images: `image00, image01, ... image98, image99`. There is only one `image_Tap` method for all these images. In this method I have `string name = ((Image)sender).Name;` so I can get my `x` and `y` from this string.